# black screen with white spinning wheel after High sierra login

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra

Thank you in advance for any useful hints.
After login I get a totally black screen or one with a spinning wheel.
I have tried the following things.
Zap nvram
Smc reset
Deleted as single user login peers.
Start as another user that was installed for migration
Verbose mode... too fast to read and ends up in the same thing

Did try shift ore safe mode.. same result. Shift makes No difference to the boot process

Started into recovery mode which doesn't want to let me repair my disk. The stupid High Sierra installation made it encrypted. Can't remember that it asked me.. it was certainly not that I wanted it.

I had restarted because Lightroom kept crashing

I have been struggling for 8 hours now and I am at wits end

NO. there is no other working mac and internet installationis not possible because I am on a 3g phone line in rural Costa Rica

There is only 1 thing that works.. the useless guest login boot into Safari mode

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a new user account by tricking the computer to going through the initial setup process.

[Instructions on re-running Apple Setup Assistant](http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/how-to-re-run-the-os-x-setup-assistant)

By creating a new user this way you can check that the issue is specific to your user account, and not your installation of macOS. If this account can login you could copy the files from the other user and the issue is resolved.

If not then you need to find a better internet connection and reinstall, someone could download the files onto a USB stick for you perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately thé browser eats Line feeds on m'y Phone... I already had another user for emergencies..

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what this has to do with anything?

Comment: Same thing.. the line completes to 75% then I get the black screen.

Comment: What line completes, the issue with your Mac not the iPhone?

Comment: Can the system be downloaded from a Windows computer? It takes about 13 hours here but maybe a friend could try while he is on a long trip with his truck. The problem is I REALLY need to use my computer

Comment: No you have to download it from macOS.

Comment: The line after login with the background photo goes to a certain spot................ since I can't do a linefeed here without posting I am doing dots........if I start in verbose mode it spills out the protocol at lightning speed.....simply can't read anything that fast and small...then it switches to the graphical screen ...goes black again...grrrrrr...is there a way to stop it going into the graphic mode so that I can READ what is going wrong

Comment: I see. Yeah so you can’t use new line characters in these comments. And verbose mode is only good for troubleshooting boot issues which isn’t what your problem is. You have having login issues.

Comment: Did you manage to create a new user account?

Comment: No. It keeps telling me my disk is read only. I have done fsck-ft and mount us 13 times it just doesn't let me delete the file Apple Setup done

Comment: Did you put a space between the flags i.e. `/sbin/fsck -fy` then `/sbin/mount -uw /`

Comment: Strangely it tells me every time that option f is not implemented ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73666/discussion-between-annette-flottwell-and-unknowndomain).

Comment: Yes all done but still moint only gets me into read only file system

Answer (score 0):

Try [reinstalling MacOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) to see if the new system files fix the issue.

> **Start up from macOS Recovery**
>
> 1. Turn on or restart your Mac, then immediately hold down Command (⌘) + R.
> 2. Release the keys when you see the Apple logo or a spinning globe.
> 3. When you see the macOS Utilities window, continue to the next section to determine whether to erase your startup disk or begin
>      installing macOS.
>
> **Install macOS**
>
> Follow these steps after starting up from macOS Recovery:
>
> 1. Choose Reinstall macOS (or Reinstall OS X) from the utilities window.
> 2. Click Continue, then follow the onscreen instructions. You'll be asked to select your disk. If you don't see it, click Show All Disks.
>      To verify eligibility to install macOS, your Mac serial number is sent
>      to Apple, and you might be asked for your Apple ID.
> 3. Click Install. Your Mac restarts after installation is complete.